# Google sheet macro when changing betwen absolute and relative during recording is not changing anything

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please can someone help me to find out where the problem is?

4 Months ago I did some recording of Absolute macro with no problem since then I didnt change anything, but now when I try to record macro the output for both options is the same (Absolute and Relative).

The format is always Relative even if I select Absolute. I tried one multiple PCs with different accounts and same result.

```
function RelativedMacro1() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1;
    if (previousSheetIndex <= 0) { previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getSheets().length; }
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[previousSheetIndex - 1], true);
    previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1;
    if (previousSheetIndex <= 0) { previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getSheets().length; }
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[previousSheetIndex - 1], true);
};
```

```
function RelativedMacro1() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1;
    if (previousSheetIndex <= 0) { previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getSheets().length; }
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[previousSheetIndex - 1], true);
    previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1;
    if (previousSheetIndex <= 0) { previousSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getSheets().length; }
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[previousSheetIndex - 1], true);
};
```

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Please see what a [mcve] is and provide one along with the error description.

Comment: Code updated and as you can see both codes are same eventhough one was recorded as Absolute macro and the other Relative. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem.  When trying to record a macro and using Absolute, if you jump tabs (Sheets), and it generates a Realive script ..

should be making things like:

`spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Backlog'), true);`

But now it's creating that previous index stuff shown in the first example.  Something changed !!!! Going between sheets is impossible unless you start at the same place every time.